# Why does Haskell interpret my Num type as an Enum?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, typeclass

I'm trying to compile the following function in Haskell to mimic differentiation of a polynomial whose constants are specified in a numerical list:

```
diff :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a]
diff [] = error "Polynomial unspecified"
diff coeff = zipWith (*) (tail coeff) [0..]
```

Haskell refuses to compile it, giving me the following reason:

```
Could not deduce (Enum a) from the context (Num a)
 arising from the arithmetic sequence `0 .. ' at fp1.hs:7:38-42
Possible fix:
 add (Enum a) to the context of the type signature for `diff'
In the third argument of `zipWith', namely `[0 .. ]'
In the expression: zipWith (*) (tail coeff) ([0 .. ])
In the definition of `diff':
diff coeff = zipWith (*) (tail coeff) ([0 .. ])
```

Why is Haskell treating the `[0..]` list as an Enum type, and how can I fix this. Bear in mind that I want to take advantage of lazy evaluation here, hence the infinite list.

Comment: Wouldn't `diff [] = []` or `diff [_] = [0]` be better?  After all, taking the fourth differential of x^2+1 should be a constant 0, not an error.

Comment: @ephemient: You are eagle-eyed! I took care of the singleton list exception after I posted the problem. The code should also read `[1..]` rather than `[0..]` for it to differentiate properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[0..]` is syntactic sugar for `enumFrom 0`, defined in class `Enum`. Because you want to generate a list of `a`s with `[0..]` the compiler demands `a` to be in class `Enum`.

You can either add the `Enum a` to the type signature of the function or work around it by generating a `[0..] :: [Integer]` and using `fromInteger` (which is defined in class `Num`) to get a `[a]` from that:

```
diff :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a]
diff [] = error "Polynomial unspecified"
diff coeff = zipWith (*) (tail coeff) (map fromInteger [0..])
```

Comment: Hmm, I'd probably write `(iterate (+1) 0)` as it's shorter, but in the end it's all the same...

Comment: Interesting. I thought it was just an infinite list of integers. The things you learn...

Comment: The funny thing is that the whole problem could have been solved by simply omitting the type signature and let the inference machine do its work.

Comment: You can also do things like `['a'..'z']` or `[1.0, 1.1 .. 2.0]` since `Char` and `Float` have `Enum` instances...

Answer (score 7):

The correct type of `diff` has to be

```
diff :: (Num a, Enum a) => [a] -> [a]
```

because the usage of `[x..]` requires the type to instantiate `Enum`.

Answer (score 3):

`[0..]` is shorthand for `enumFrom 0` [See here](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#arithmetic-sequences)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick summary of what the compiler sees when it looks at this function:

- [0..] is a list of things that have both Num and Enum instances. It has to be a Num because of the '0', and it has to be an Enum because of the '..'
- I'm being asked to apply (*) to the elements of coeff and [0..] one by one.  Since both arguments to (*) have to be the same type and [0..] has an instance for Enum, coeff must also have an instance for Enum.
- Error!  The type signature of diff only mentions that coeff has an instance for Num, but I've already determined that it must at least have an instance for Enum too.

Comment: This explains why another function did not throw up this error. That function involved a simple `zip`: `(a,b) <- zip coeff [0..]` returns tuples, which can have mixed data types.